# woocommerce after login redirect

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

My In my woocommerce login form successful login it is redirection to shop page I did,

And after login error it should be same page but it goes /wp-login.php.I got some codes but it is working when I enter wrong username or password but when I put empty user name or password it is going /wp-login.php.

Here is the code

```
function my_front_end_login_fail( $username,$password ){
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ){
      wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login_failed=failed' );
      exit;
    }
}
```

Can you help me.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to redirect after login :

```
<?php
/**
* Redirect users to custom URL based on their role after login
*
* @param string $redirect
* @param object $user
* @return string
*/
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
  // Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
  $role = $user->roles[0];
  $dashboard = admin_url();
  $myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
  if( $role == 'administrator' ) {
    //Redirect administrators to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
  } elseif ( $role == 'shop-manager' ) {
    //Redirect shop managers to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
  } elseif ( $role == 'editor' ) {
    //Redirect editors to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
  } elseif ( $role == 'author' ) {
    //Redirect authors to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
  } elseif ( $role == 'customer' || $role == 'subscriber' ) {
    //Redirect customers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
    $redirect = $myaccount;
  } else {
    //Redirect any other role to the previous visited page or, if not available, to the home
    $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
  }
  return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep,This code shows after login redirect but I want to redirect after login error,my code works on error username and password ,but empty username and passwordit is not working..

Comment: ok you problem is that you want to redirect user to shop page if they have fill no username and password.

Comment: No sandeep,Normally in woocommerce if we are entering wrong user name and password it is going www.websitename/wp-login.php with error message,login customers don't like to go www.websitename/wp-login.php instead of that link I want to display same page with error message,That code(top of the page) working only if we are entering wrong user name or password,If we are giving blank username or password it is going wp-login.php,Could you understand my issue...

Answer (score 4):

redirects for login / logout

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_redirect');

function login_redirect($redirect_to) {
    return home_url();
}

add_action('wp_logout','logout_redirect');

function logout_redirect(){
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
```