# Woocommerce Redirect Customers to Previous Page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I have applied all available snippets including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342186/woocommerce-after-login-redirect), but when customers log in, it redirects to My Account Page which is annoying. How to solve this?

Why doesn't below code work?

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
  function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {

      $role = $user->roles[0];

    if ( $role == 'customer' ) {
      //Redirect to the previous visited page or, if not available, to home
         $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
    }
    return $redirect;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a higher priority? It's possible that another plugin is overriding the filter you're trying to use.

Comment: @indextwo, Yes, I have tried with higher priority (several). But it's still redirecting me to My Account page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `wp_get_referer()` at the point of `woocommerce_login_redirect` filter will target the account page and you need to get the referer of the referer. The second thing is that it doesn't work for me and many others, while `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` grabs the referer without a problem.

This could be done using PHP sessions, but they cause problems on Ngix and Varnish with server caching.

The possible solutions are:

Pass a hidden referer URL field as shown here:

https://gist.github.com/EvanHerman/492c09fbb584e0c428ae

Use a database to temporarily store previous page URLs for each user ID. A query string with a unique ID is added to WooCommerce login form's URL. I use this solution in my plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-settings-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Do you have a way to make it work with WooCommerce Social Login at the same time?