# WooCommerce - redirect to previous page after login

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been searching for plugins and snippets which would handle it for hours, but no success. Every single answer doesn't work for me. I have "Log in" link in menu, leading to WooCommerce "My account" page, which shows login form. I want customers to return to page where "Log in" link was clicked after successful login.

`wp_get_referer()` doesn't return anything and `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` returns my account page if put within function hooked to `woocommerce_login_redirect` (I used PHP debug console to check).

Here is my code:

```
// Redirect user after login.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    // Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
    $role = $user->roles[0];
    $dashboard = admin_url();       

    if (in_array($role, array('administrator', 'shop_manager', 'editor', 'author', 'contributor'))) {
        $redirect = $dashboard;         
    } elseif (in_array($role, array('customer', 'subscriber'))) {
        $redirect = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];          
    } else {
        $redirect = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];       
    }

    return $redirect;

}
```

Here is where filter which I used appears in WooCommerce code:

```
/** 
   * Process the login form. 
   */ 
  public static function process_login() { 
      $nonce_value = isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ? $_POST['_wpnonce'] : ''; 
      $nonce_value = isset( $_POST['woocommerce-login-nonce'] ) ? $_POST['woocommerce-login-nonce'] : $nonce_value; 

      if ( ! empty( $_POST['login'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'woocommerce-login' ) ) { 

          try { 
              $creds = array( 
                  'user_password' => $_POST['password'],  
                  'remember' => isset( $_POST['rememberme'] ),  
 ); 

              $username = trim( $_POST['username'] ); 
              $validation_error = new WP_Error(); 
              $validation_error = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_process_login_errors', $validation_error, $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] ); 

              if ( $validation_error->get_error_code() ) { 
                  throw new Exception( '<strong>' . __( 'Error:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong> ' . $validation_error->get_error_message() ); 
              } 

              if ( empty( $username ) ) { 
                  throw new Exception( '<strong>' . __( 'Error:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong> ' . __( 'Username is required.', 'woocommerce' ) ); 
              } 

              if ( is_email( $username ) && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_username_from_email', true ) ) { 
                  $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username ); 

                  if ( isset( $user->user_login ) ) { 
                      $creds['user_login'] = $user->user_login; 
                  } else { 
                      throw new Exception( '<strong>' . __( 'Error:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong> ' . __( 'A user could not be found with this email address.', 'woocommerce' ) ); 
                  } 
              } else { 
                  $creds['user_login'] = $username; 
              } 

              // On multisite, ensure user exists on current site, if not add them before allowing login. 
              if ( is_multisite() ) { 
                  $user_data = get_user_by( 'login', $username ); 

                  if ( $user_data && ! is_user_member_of_blog( $user_data->ID, get_current_blog_id() ) ) { 
                      add_user_to_blog( get_current_blog_id(), $user_data->ID, 'customer' ); 
                  } 
              } 

              // Perform the login 
              $user = wp_signon( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_login_credentials', $creds ), is_ssl() ); 

              if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) { 
                  $message = $user->get_error_message(); 
                  $message = str_replace( '<strong>' . esc_html( $creds['user_login'] ) . '</strong>', '<strong>' . esc_html( $username ) . '</strong>', $message ); 
                  throw new Exception( $message ); 
              } else { 

                  if ( ! empty( $_POST['redirect'] ) ) { 
                      $redirect = $_POST['redirect']; 
                  } elseif ( wp_get_referer() ) { 
                      $redirect = wp_get_referer(); 
                  } else { 
                      $redirect = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ); 
                  } 

                  wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', $redirect, $user ) ); 
                  exit; 
              } 
          } catch ( Exception $e ) { 
              wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'login_errors', $e->getMessage() ), 'error' ); 
              do_action( 'woocommerce_login_failed' ); 
          } 
      } 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code, i hope it helps you. 
 Paste the below code in current active theme **functions.php** file.

```
// start global session for saving the referer url
function start_session() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);

// get  referer url and save it 
function redirect_url() {
    if (! is_user_logged_in()) {
        $_SESSION['referer_url'] = wp_get_referer();
    } else {
        session_destroy();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_url' );

//login redirect 
function login_redirect() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['referer_url'])) {
        wp_redirect($_SESSION['referer_url']);
    } else {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 1100, 2);
```

Comment: I learned that the use of sessions breaks server-based caching such as Nginx and Varnish, so it must be taken into account when using this solution. I've just released a plugin among its many features, solves WooCommerce redirects to the previous page in a non-invasive way, using a query string and operating on database to get the previously visited page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-settings-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 3):

I tried the answer of @dineshkashera but it throws an error as starting a session is not a good practice and also wp_get_referer hook is not working and thus $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

So my only solution is creating a cookie that will save our previous link.

Here's my Code:

```
//First we need to set a cookie that will save the previous url
setcookie('nlcrc', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time() + 86000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);

//Then initiate Woocommerce redirect hook

//This is for the WC login redirect
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wcc_redirects', 9999, 2);

//I have added also WC registration redirect
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'wcc_redirects', 9999, 1);

//Then this will be the handler
function wcc_redirects ($redirect) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['nlcrc'])) {
        $redirect = $_COOKIE['nlcrc'];
        return $redirect;
    } else {
        $redirect = home_url();
        return $redirect;
    }
}
```

or you can also somewhat quick and dirty with Javascript. If your default login page is Woocommerce My Account Page.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_cstm_login_redirect', 99 );

function wc_cstm_login_redirect () {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    history.go(-2);
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: First solution did work like a charm with WP 5.8.3 (january 2022).

Answer (score 0):

**We have to use WordPress referrer function:**

For example, set referrer URL in session or hidden field by clicking on add to cart button or any button to store previous URL. Once login or register success add WooCommerce success login redirect to that URL.

Read [about the Referrer function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_referer/).

Here's an answer about the [WooCommerce login redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342186/woocommerce-after-login-redirect).

Comment: I mentioned in my post, that `wp_get_referer()` doesn't return anything in my filter function. 2nd link is one of solutions which didn't work for me.

Comment: use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` instead of `wp_get_referer()`
We need to customise into html and also We need to customise `wp_redirect()` function.

Comment: That's what I'm using in my example and it returns "My account" page.

Comment: try this if `wp_get_referer()` not working. 
`$url = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$url = $url['path'];
$url = substr($url, 1);`

Comment: It also directs to "My account" page. Fortunately solution posted by dineshkashera worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your prolem

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', function(){
   
       wp_safe_redirect(wp_get_referer());

}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//First we need to set a cookie that will save the previous url
setcookie('nlcrc', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time() + 86000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);

//Then initiate Woocommerce redirect hook

//This is for the WC login redirect
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wcc_redirects', 9999, 2);

//I have added also WC registration redirect
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'wcc_redirects', 9999, 1);

//Then this will be the handler
function wcc_redirects ($redirect) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['nlcrc'])) {
        $redirect = $_COOKIE['nlcrc'];
        return $redirect;
    } else {
        $redirect = home_url();
        return $redirect;
    }
}
```

This code snippet works best for me, but here is a tricky thing. When user is resetting his password and logging in with new pass, the snippet redirects him to reset password page again. How can we fix it please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).