# Redirect page after WooCommerce login

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect, woocommerce

I need to be able to redirect users to particular pages after WooCommerce login depending on which link they've clicked.

For example, if they click the 'login' link they go to the WooCommerce login form and then are redirected to the 'my account' page. This is default behaviour, which is fine.

However, I have another link which goes to a private WordPress page. If they click this link I want them to go to that page after logging in via the standard WooCommerce login form, and not to the 'my account' page.

It's straightforward enough to redirect users after login using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 2 );
function login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    return 'https://testsite.test/private-page/';
}
```

But then everyone gets redirected to that page however they've arrived at the WooCommerce login page.

The first answer here looked promising but doesn't work: [WooCommerce - redirect to previous page after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56292237/woocommerce-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login)

If I error_log

```
$_SESSION['referer_url']
```

from that code it shows /my-account/ which isn't what I need. I need the URL of the private page from the link.

Any help on this gratefully appreciated.

Thanks.